# How to get properties from gx_mappanel layers

Tags: geoext

I have gx_mappannel with id:mappannel. I added two layers to this panel: OSM layer and one vector layer, here is the sample code:

```
          Ext.onReady(function(){
              ...
              {
                xtype: "gx_mappanel",
                ref: "mapPanel",
                id:"mappanel",
                region: "center",
                title: 'my title',
                map:{
                    maxExtent: extnt
                    numZoomLevels:zomlevel,

                    projection: myprojection,
                    center:theCenter
                  },

                 layers:[new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),

                       vlayer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vlayer",
                           {
                            projection:myprojection,
                            strategies:[new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                            protocol:new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                                url: "mygeojson", 
                                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                            }),

                          })

                     ]
             },
            .....
        }
```

I checked that the two layers are added to the pannel using this code

```
           myPanel = Ext.getCmp("mappanel");
           console.log(mapPanel.map.layers.length);
```

The console prints 2, and that is right.

The vector layer produces geojson data of the form

"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[938423.3125,6653195.5],"type":"Point"},"type":"feature","properties":{"count":7}},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[903914.25,6653195.5],"type":"Point"},"type":"feature","properties":{"count":7}},{"geometry":{"coordinates":[888329.5625,6644321.5],"type":"Point"},"type":"feature","properties":{"count":5}},....

I want to iterate over the vector layer and calculate sum of the "count" values. I mean this one-("properties":{"count":7}). I made some tries but not successful yet.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
syntax in general:

var layer_sum=0;
    for(var i=0;i<vlayer.features.length;i++)
    { 
    layer_sum=layer_sum+vlayer.features[i].attributes.count;
    }
    console.log(layer_sum);
```

depending on the question if you want to parse values as int / float you could replace the row then with

```
 layer_sum=layer_sum+vlayer.features[i].attributes.count;
```

with

```
 layer_sum=layer_sum+parseInt(vlayer.features[i].attributes.count);
```

or

```
layer_sum=layer_sum+parseFloat(vlayer.features[i].attributes.count);
```

PS: make sure that all features are added to the layer before you start the for loop, for example with listening to the loadend event

```
vlayer.events.register("loadend",map,function()
 {
   console.log(vlayer.features.length);

 }
 );
```

I just set up a jsfiddle to demonstate what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/3any8tk8/

Comment: Hi, Thomas thank you for fast reply. for the line:i=0;features.length  returns zero. But when I run my code the geojson data is available. how can I use "featuresadded event' to test this?

Comment: can you just run vlayer.features.length from firebug or your developer tools after the layer is loaded?

Comment: i meant the loadend event (corrected now in my answer). see my additional lines of code above

Comment: Hi Thomas The code: vlayer.events.register("loadend",mappanel.map,function()
 {
   console.log(vlayer.features.length);

 }
 );  I modified map as mappanel.map and it shows that length is 585. but the other code:var layer_sum=0;
                            for(var i=0;i<player.features.length;i++)
                            { 
                            layer_sum=layer_sum+parseInt(vlayer.features[i].attributes.count);
                            }
                            console.log(layer_sum); gives me length zero, is there something missed?

Comment: you have written player.features.length instead of vlayer.features.length

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much! I put the two codes together like this: vlayer.events.register("loadend",mapPanel.map,function()
                 {
                       //console.log(vlayer.features.length);
                       var layer_sum=0;
                            for(var i=0;i<player.features.length;i++)
                            { 
                            layer_sum=layer_sum+parseInt(vlayer.features[i].attributes.count);
                            }
                            console.log(layer_sum);

                     }
                     );  and it calculates the sum.